# Find task in MS Project by custom field value

Tags: vba, ms-project

i'm currently using below function to find a MS project task based on custom field value, it works perfectly when a parent task object is provided, it only loops through children tasks. The problem is that now in plan target task could be placed any where in plan and it takes some time looping through all the ~3k tasks in plan trying to find the correct task based on custom field value. Is there a way i could do this faster?

```
   **'sub to test Function**
   Public Sub TestFunction()
     
      Dim TaskObject as Object
      Dim MSapp as Object '<- MS project application
      Dim ErrMsg as String          

      set TaskObject = funGetTaskByFieldRef(objMSPapp:=MSapp, 
                                           fieldValue:="Key1234", 
                                           fieldName:= "customForeingKeyField",
                                           ErrMsg:= ErrMsg)
      if TaskObject is nothing then
        MsgBox ErrMsg
      else
        Debug.Print TaskObject.UniqueID & " - " & TaskObject.Name
      end if

   End Sub
 
  **'Function - - -**
 Public Function funGetTaskByFieldRef(ByRef objMSPapp As Object, ByVal fieldValue As String, _ 
                                      ByVal fieldName As String, _
                             Optional ByRef objParentTask As Object, _
                             Optional ByRef ErrMsg As String = vbNullString) As Object

    '<VARIABLES>
    Dim obMSPprj As Object
    Dim tsk As Object
    Dim tmpValue As String
    '</VARIABLES>
    
    '<FUN> ---
            
            'set temporal var Microsoft Project
            Set obMSPprj = objMSPapp.ActiveProject
            
            'using project
            With obMSPprj
                    
                    'check if parent task has been provided
                    If Not objParentTask Is Nothing Then
                            
                            'loop through each child
                                    For Each tsk In objParentTask.OutlineChildren
                                            
                                            tmpValue = funSetGetMSPval(objMSPapp, tsk, 0, "Get", fieldName)
                                            
                                            If tmpValue = fieldValue Then
                                                
                                                'retunr UID
                                                Set funGetTaskByFieldRef = tsk
                                                
                                                'exit function
                                                Exit Function
                                                
                                            End If
                                    
                                    Next tsk

                    Else
                            'loop through each task
                            For Each tsk In .Tasks
                                        
                                        tmpValue = funSetGetMSPval(objMSPapp, tsk, 0, "Get", fieldName)
                                         
                                         If tmpValue = fieldValue Then
                                                
                                                'retunr UID
                                                    Set funGetTaskByFieldRef = tsk
                                                
                                                'exit function
                                                    Exit Function
                                                    
                                          End If
                                          
                            Next tsk
                    
                    End If
                    
            End With
            
            'if there is no exact match for task name return -1
            Set funGetTaskByFieldRef = Nothing
            ErrMsg = "Task not found"
            
    '<FUN> ---
  
  
End Function

**'Encapsulated sub-function **
Public Function funSetGetMSPval(ByRef objMSPapp As Object, ByRef objEntObj As Object, _
                                ByVal intPjFieldType As Integer, ByVal strAction As String, _
                       Optional ByVal strFldName As String, _
                       Optional ByVal strVal As String) As Variant
                
                'pjProject = 2
                'pjResource =1
                'pjTask = 0
    
    With objMSPapp
            
            Select Case strAction
                        
                        Case "Set"
                                                           
                                On Error Resume Next
                                objEntObj.SetField .FieldNameToFieldConstant(strFldName, intPjFieldType), strVal
                                    
                                If Not Err.Number <> 0 Then
                                        'catch error
                                End If
                                
                                On Error GoTo 0
                                
                                funSetGetMSPval = True
                                
                        Case "Get"
                                
                                funSetGetMSPval = objEntObj.getfield(.FieldNameToFieldConstant(strFldName, intPjFieldType))
                                        
            End Select
    
    End With

End Function
```

Hope there is someone that has a better way to do this.

thank you.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way i could do this faster?

Yes, use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method.

```
Public Sub FindTask()

Dim TaskObject As Object
Dim MSapp As Object
Set MSapp = Application

Dim found As Boolean
found = MSapp.Find(Field:="customForeingKeyField", Test:="equals", Value:="Key1234")

If found Then
    Set TaskObject = MSapp.ActiveCell.Task
    Debug.Print TaskObject.UniqueID & " - " & TaskObject.Name
Else
    MsgBox "Task not found"
End If

End Sub
```